# Error in Launching Watchkit Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I am getting the following error while try to run my app in watchkit extension.
[image: wachkit error]

I also tried to clean and re-build my project but no any result.

Please help me to solve this...

Answer (score 2):

fixed this issue In my case by going to the simulator's watch companion app, unchecking the installation for the watch app, then turning it back on. Nothing else worked